# URL Rewriting - Multi-Domain - Remove Folder In Path on Primary Domain

Tags: url, rewriting

This challenge is related to URL Rewriting in using both a primary domain with a fictitious folder and as many secondary domains (without the fictitious folder) as needed. The idea is that the site will have a default domain that anyone can use, but also will allow users to use their own domain. Both also need the extensions removed at the end. I’ll outline how it should work. I have almost everything working except one thing and I’m hoping someone can assist or shed some light. This is a VS 2012 application that uses IIS.

**PRIMARY DOMAIN URLS**

```
www.primarydomain.com/anyfictitiousname/page1 
www.primarydomain.com/anyfictitiousname2/page2 
www.primarydomain.com/anyfictitiousname3/somepath/page3
```

**REWRITTEN PRIMARY DOMAIN URLS**

```
www.primarydomain.com/page1.aspx (or better yet www.primarydomain.com/page1.aspx?i=anyfictitiousname)
www.primarydomain.com/page2.aspx (or better yet www.primarydomain.com/page2.aspx?i=anyfictitiousname2)
www.primarydomain.com/somepath/page3.aspx (or better yet www.primarydomain.com/somepath/page3.aspx?i=anyfictitiousname3)
```

**SECONDARY DOMAIN URLS**

```
www.secondarydomain1.com/page1 
www.secondarydomain2.com/page2
www.secondarydomain3.com/somepath/page3
```

**REWRITTEN SECONDARY DOMAIN URLS**

```
www.secondarydomain1.com/page1.aspx 
www.secondarydomain2.com/page2.aspx 
www.secondarydomain3.com/somepath/page3.aspx
```

All of the above actually work with my current rewriting code (which I’ve listed below), except when using the primary domain and not including the file at the end of the URL, it falls apart. Essentially, if I assign the URL “www.primarydomain.com/personname” to a user, I want to be able to go to that address to load the default page rather than having to type “www. primarydomain.com/personname/default” if that makes sense. What ends up happening is the following:

```
www.primarydomain.com/personname => www.primarydomain.com/personname.aspx
www.primarydomain.com/personname/ => www.primarydomain.com/personname/.aspx
```

What I want to happen in this case is the following:

```
www.primarydomain.com/personname => www.primarydomain.com/default.aspx (or better yet www.primarydomain.com/default.aspx?i=personname)
www.primarydomain.com/personname/ => www.primarydomain.com/default.aspx (or better yet www.primarydomain.com/default.aspx?i=personname)
```

I’m new to URL rewriting, so I’m not sure of the correct approach, but essentially after the first rule is performed or as a part of the first rule, if {R:2} is nothing or “/”, I’d like to rewrite it as “default.aspx”. Even if a redirect is performed in which “default.aspx” is added to the URL, that is okay too, but I don’t want to have to make the end-user type the file path at the end when entering the URL into the browser. Here is my current rewriting code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Handle Primary URLs" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([_0-9a-z-]+)/(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}.aspx?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="remove aspx">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```